# Getting ClassCastException in Hive ORC table

Tags: hive, cloudera, orc

Using cloudera 8.1. In Hive, loaded a table in ORC format with a CSV file. Getting this error on attempting to query the loaded table:

Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.HiveVarcharWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable

Comment: Please provide details about metadata and data

Answer (score 0):

This is common issue I see lots of people make,

You can create hive external table with CSV format and then say 
"INSERT INTO TABLE FINAL SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE" which will copy the CSV data into ORC table.

By using this method Hive will convert the CSV data into ORC using inbuilt libraries.

Comment: Yes that could be done. But, when qureying from the final table which is in ORC format, getting the above error.

Comment: The issue is one of the columns defined as INT has string.

Comment: From the exception message it seems like that. However, changing the specification from ORC to Parquet, it worked fine. I think there is some kind of bug for ORC serde implementation in the Hive package in Cloudera version 8.1.